# Match within string, but ignore matches between brackets - Regex and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string examples:

```
 "1. go [south], but look out for the trout pouting [lout]"
 "2. go [south], but be wary of the pouting [lout]"
 "3. go [south], but be wary of the sullen-looking [lout]"
```

I'd like the query word **out** to match if it appears in each string, but is ignored if it's between brackets. So I'm looking to match:

1. *True* for **out**, **trout**, *and* **pouting**
2. *True* for **pouting**
3. *False*

I've managed to get as far as this expression:

```
/[^\(\)\[\]]out\s(?![\]])/ig
```

However, it's only matching the first string for **out** and **trout** .

I've figured out that the whitespace character is the influencing factor here for not matching **pouting**, but getting rid of it matches everything between the brackets, too.

What would be the correct regular expression for this?

Comment: Is it always one word inside brackets, without spaces?

Comment: Try changing `out\s` to `out[a-z0-9 ]` as you can have characters after `out`

Comment: Ah, I was so close! Thanks for your answer, Rajesh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `[...]` are balanced and unescaped, you can use a negative lookahead based search:

```
/out(?![^\[\]]*\])/
```

`(?![^\[\]]*\])` is a negative lookahead that asserts that we don't have a `]` following non-`[` and non-`]` characters ahead thus making sure we're not matching `out` inside a `[...]`.

Javascript code to build your regex:

```
search = "out";
var regex = new RexExp(search + "(?![^\\[\\]]*\\])", "g");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d0TQm1/1)

Comment: Although Rajesh gave a good answer above, I'm going to go with your method, as it's more robust. Many thanks for your help, Anubhava.